# EditText control in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textwatcher

I'm making a validation form with EditText. I have three EditText boxes and I want to make sure the user types something on `ed1` before going to `ed2`. So, I want to block the user from going to `ed2` unless they put something in `ed1`. If `ed1` is null, the cursor won't go to `ed2`. Can someone help me?

```
final EditText ed1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.one);
final EditText ed2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.two);

TextWatcher watcher = new TextWatcher() {
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if (ed1.getText().toString().equals("")) {
            ed2.requestFocus();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: you should simply use the `setError` to display message when user press submit otherwise you need to create a chain where every edit text check the non-empty criteria of previous edittext

Comment: Have u tried my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `TextUtil` to check for empty inputs.
2. Use `editText.setEnabled()` method or `editText.setActivated()` according to use.
   Also, use drawable.xml to change the style of the `View`

   ```
       final EditText ed1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.one);
       final EditText ed2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.two);

       TextWatcher watcher = new TextWatcher() {
           @Override
           public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

           }

           @Override
           public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

           }

           public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
               if (TextUtils.isEmpty(ed1.getText())) {
                   //ed2.requestFocus();
                   ed2.setEnabled(false);
               }
           }
       };
   ```

Let me know if it is helpful to you.

Comment: thanks for trying but it didn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

Initially make ed2 as disabled

```
android:enabled="false"
```

and in class file use

```
   ed1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            if (s.length()>0) {
                ed2.setEnabled(true);
            }
            else
            {
                ed2.setEnabled(false);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: that also did not work. it just block the second ed2 if i set it to false. but it does not get activated afterwards.